# JAVA SecurityManager - custom BasicPermission with multiple actions

Tags: java, security, policy, securitymanager

I created the following policy file:

```
grant {
    permission StackPermission "use,save";
};
```

In order to access it, I run my JVM using the following params:

```
-Djava.security.manager -Djava.security.policy=my.policy
```

My code looks like this:

```
SecurityManager sec = System.getSecurityManager();
sec.checkPermission( new StackPermission( "use,save" ) );
```

Everything works great, but I want to go a bit more granular, without checking the "save" action:

```
sec.checkPermission( new StackPermission( "use" ) );
```

It seems this doesn't work even though my policy specifies both "use" and "save" alltogether, what should I do in order to provide such functionality?

Many thanks, 
Vlad

Answer (score 0):

Generally permission constructor come in three flavours: no-args, `name`, and `name` and `actions`. I don't have the source code to your `StackPermissions` (I suggest putting it in a non-default package, btw), but I'm guessing you've just got `name` but are treating it like `action`. Kind of a shame that Java allows constructors to be overloaded even on arity.

So, put the class in a named package and add a `name` before the `action` in both the class and the policy file.

(In general I suggest getting away from the "Java 2 Security Model" as quickly as possible. Instead have one checked method that returns an object with the capability of doing the privileged actions without further security checks (an *object-capability* in the lingo). Do the same in the higher layers of code.)